# what's the technical difference between these two ways of sorting in python?

Tags: python, sorting, key

Ok,so the exercise is this:

```
#To order a list of strings considering the number of vowels in decreasing order,
#then the whole length in increasing order, then the reverse alphabetical order.
example:
#['pear', 'peach', 'apple', 'banana', 'avocado'] ->
#['avocado', 'banana', 'pear', 'peach', 'apple']
def key_vowels(x):
    pass

l = ['pear', 'peach', 'apple', 'banana', 'avocado']
sorted(l) # <- change this to sort with the new key
```

i tried solving it this way(the most intuitive one), but the last two elements of the expected output are exchanged:

```
def key_vowels(x):
    vowels = set("aeiouAEIOU")

    return -sum(1 for char in x if char in vowels), -len(x), x[::-1]

    l = ['pear', 'peach', 'apple', 'banana', 'avocado']
    sorted(l, key=key_vowels)
```

After several attempts i came up with this idea (to invert everything), so:

```
def key_vowels(x):
    vowels = set("aeiouAEIOU")
    
    return sum(1 for char in x if char in vowels), -len(x), x

    l = ['pear', 'peach', 'apple', 'banana', 'avocado']
sorted(l, key=key_vowels, reverse=True)
```

But i can't still understand what's the difference between my initial method and the last one. Thank you in advance!

*edit: sorry, there was a minus before the sum in the first example*

Comment: You have 3 criteria, inverting the last one isn't going to have the same effect as reversing the sort order

Comment: Well maybe explain why you'd think it would be the same so we can tell you where you are wrong? Also I don't think "reverse alphabetical order" means the reverse word in alphabetical order...

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code, I'm pretty sure you're not running what you shared.

Comment: `sorted` returns a sorted list without modifying the iterable you are sorting. It makes no sense to call `sorted` without saving the return value.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you do this:

```
sum(1 for char in x if char in vowels), -len(x), x[::-1]
```

So, that's "the number of vowels in the word", the negative length of the word, and the word itself in reverse order. You're sorting ascending, so the result will have the word with the fewest vowels first, for words with equal numbers of vowels the longest vowel first, and for words with equal numbers of vowels and the same length, the last word alphabetically first.

If you run this:

```
l = ['pear', 'peach', 'apple', 'banana', 'avocado']
print({x: key_vowels(x) for x in sorted(l, key=key_vowels)})
```

This is the outcome, showing why you get the order you do:

```
{'apple': (2, -5, 'elppa'), 'peach': (2, -5, 'hcaep'), 'pear': (2, -4, 'raep'), 'banana': (3, -6, 'ananab'), 'avocado': (4, -7, 'odacova')}
```

If you do the same for the second solution, you get this:

```
{'apple': (2, -5, 'apple'), 'peach': (2, -5, 'peach'), 'pear': (2, -4, 'pear'), 'banana': (3, -6, 'banana'), 'avocado': (4, -7, 'avocado')}
```

So, there's a clear difference already, and it's not an 'inversion' by any means. However, on top of this change, you changed the call to `sorted` to:

```
sorted(l, key=key_vowels, reverse=True)
```

So, if you do the same as above, you get this outcome:

```
{'avocado': (4, -7, 'avocado'), 'banana': (3, -6, 'banana'), 'pear': (2, -4, 'pear'), 'peach': (2, -5, 'peach'), 'apple': (2, -5, 'apple')}
```

Now you're getting the most vowels first (instead of last), for the same number of vowels the shortest word first, and for the same number of vowels and the same length, the words in reverse alphabetical order. (which is what was asked)